# Seeing junk characters in file written using PrintWriter.write()

Tags: java

While using PrintWriter.write() method, I have noticed that sometimes [ issues is observed randomly] junk characters creep into the end/result file.

Tried an alternate API also as below.

StandardOpenOption[] openOption = {StandardOpenOption.CREATE , StandardOpenOption.APPEND};
            writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(outFile, this.charsetEncoding ,openOption);

This issue is being seen in a linux server using openjdk.

java version "1.8.0_202"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-b32)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.202-b32, mixed mode)

Code :

```
   osw = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(outFile, true), "ISO-8859-1");
        coldelimiter = "\t";
        rowdelimiter = "\n";

        writer = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(osw));

        while (iterator.hasNext()) {

            final DataToWrite data = iterator.next();
            writer.write(data.getDataName());
            writer.write(coldelimiter);

            }
            writer.write(rowdelimiter);
            writer.flush();
```

Expected :

testSystem  testSystem      1   14  1       managedSystem   1   1   1310    2019-04-10 01:00:00 2019-04-10  10  Alpha   testSystem      +0100   1   0   4   15      29201   15MIN   2019-04-10 00:00:00 2019    13

Actual :

testSystem  testSystem      1   14  1       manag)edSystem  1   1   1310    2019-04-10 01:00:00 2019-04-10  10  Alpha   testSystem      +0100   1   0   4   15      29201   15MIN   2019-04-10 00:00:00 2019    13      `q

I expect new line [ \n ] at the end, but sometimes junk characters like `q,) etc are getting appended at random columns.

Any idea why this is happening and how this can be avoided ?

Comment: It is difficult to give a definitive answer, without knowing your data, however I suspect the problem you have is the charset you have given is `"ISO8859-1"` did you mean `"ISO-8859-1"` or maybe you need something more generic like `"UTF-8"`
See the following link for more documentation on charsets [https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html]

Comment: Yes, it was a typo Bill. Its ISO-8859-1.

Comment: Are you flushing the PrintWriter. I note that the docs at [https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html] state that for all (but the autoflush) constructors "Creates a new PrintWriter, **without automatic line flushing**"